# Javascript formatting null value in table cell

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet within my react component that passes in a transaction object with several fields.  Why does it not work?

I'm trying to only show a value formatted with a $ sign if the value is not null.

> ${!isNaN(transaction.debit) ?
>   parseFloat(transaction.debit).toFixed(2) : null}

Is there a better way to do this?  My array of data basically has debit fields that may not have a value and in that case I just don't want to display anything in the cell.

Comment: isNaN(null) --> false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about concatenating the string `'$'` to the beginning of your float if the `transaction.debit` value is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or it is `0` (assuming we want to show a value for `0`) - otherwise show an empty string.

```
{transaction.debit || transaction.debit === 0 ? '$' + parseFloat(transaction.debit).toFixed(2) : ''}
```